limit amount of virtual monitors created at startup (usbmmidd)
I've met a problem setting up a remote desktop - AnyDesk couldn't connect since remote computer had no monitor. And I've found a workaround - I've setup a virtual monitor with usbmmidd that adds a new monitor with command deviceinstaller64 enableidd 1.
I've created a batch file with this command and added it to shell:startup so it will set it up automatically. But since shell:startup is running multiple times during one session this command keeps creating new virtual monitors (up to 4).
Any ideas how can I make sure that it will add just 1 virtual monitor?

Here's the script implementing counting monitors snippet from this answer.

@echo off
setlocal

rem Store the current directory
set "original_dir=%CD%"

rem Change directory to the desired location
cd C:\usbmmidd_v2

rem Check the number of monitors
for /F %%M in ('wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Service='monitor' and Status='OK'" get DeviceID /VALUE ^| find /C "="') do set "monitor_count=%%M"

rem If the monitor count is 0, enable the device with deviceinstaller64
if "%monitor_count%"=="0" (
    deviceinstaller64 enableidd 1
    echo Monitors enabled.
) else (
    echo Monitor already present, =%monitor_count%, no action needed.
)

rem Change directory back to the original location
cd /D "%original_dir%"

endlocal


